# Telerik TrackBallInfoTemplate not displaying

Tags: wpf, telerik

```
<telerik:RadCartesianChart Name="ClientClaimsLineGraph" PanOffset ="{Binding Path=ClientClaimsLineGraphPan, Mode=TwoWay}" Zoom="{Binding Path=ClientClaimsLineGraphZoom, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
      <telerik:RadContextMenu>
         <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Reset Zoom" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action ClientClaimsLineGraphResetZoom]" Icon="{StaticResource ResetZoomImage}"/>
      </telerik:RadContextMenu>    
     </telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>   

     <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Behaviors>
       <telerik:ChartPanAndZoomBehavior ZoomMode="Both"/>
          <telerik:ChartTrackBallBehavior ShowIntersectionPoints="True" ShowTrackInfo="False"/>
     </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Behaviors>

     <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
       <telerik:DateTimeCategoricalAxis Title="Date" MajorTickInterval="12" LabelFormat="MM/yyyy"/>
          </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>

     <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
        <telerik:LinearAxis Title="Costs" LabelFormat="c0"/>
           </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>

     <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
       <telerik:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding ClientSummary}" ValueBinding="Cost" CategoryBinding="Date" Stroke="Red">

         <telerik:LineSeries.LegendSettings>
           <telerik:SeriesLegendSettings Title="Costs"/>
         </telerik:LineSeries.LegendSettings>

     <telerik:LineSeries.TrackBallTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Fill="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </telerik:LineSeries.TrackBallTemplate>

    <telerik:LineSeries.TrackBallInfoTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="FOOOO!" Margin="0, 50, 0, 0" Foreground="Black" Width="500" Height="500"/>
       </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:LineSeries.TrackBallInfoTemplate>                     
</telerik:LineSeries>
   <telerik:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding ClientSummary}" ValueBinding="Claims" CategoryBinding="Date" Stroke="Blue">

<telerik:LineSeries.LegendSettings>
   <telerik:SeriesLegendSettings Title="Claims"/>
</telerik:LineSeries.LegendSettings>
<telerik:LineSeries.VerticalAxis>
   <telerik:LinearAxis Title="Claims" HorizontalLocation="Right" LabelFormat="n0"/>
</telerik:LineSeries.VerticalAxis>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example I used had the **track info turned off**!

```
<telerik:ChartTrackBallBehavior ShowIntersectionPoints="True" ShowTrackInfo="True" />
```